# CodeIgniter - "A Database Error Occurred" (controllers/Login.php)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to configure a webapp using CodeIgniter on MAMP locally, however, I keep getting this error.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> > Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
> >
> > Filename: controllers/Login.php
> >
> > Line Number: 8

This is Line Number: 8 in controllers/Login.php

```
parent::__construct();
```

This is my database configuration in config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array (
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '*******',
    'password' => '*********',
    'database' => '**************',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I am very confused. I looked at similar stackoverflow posts, however, my issue is a bit different.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect using those credentials and any other MySQL client?

Comment: Have you ensured that the local database service is running and listening for connections?

Comment: @tadman Yes, I can connect using those credentials on the live website.

Comment: @Kisaragi The database is running on phpMyAdmin so I assumed its already listening to it.

Comment: Can you check if the database is running on port 3306?

Comment: @JashParekh This fixed my issue as I did not configure my ports to what the app and database were being served on.

Comment: @caliper great, happy coding!